# Rails 4 - controller not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can hit the `importers#import_vendor_ledger` action but I can't seem to hit the `importers#import_chart_of_accounts` action via the `redirect_based_on(arg)` method in`uploaders#upload_file`. Please help!

NOTE: I left out some code that I didn't think was necessary to see

My code:

routes.rb

```
resources :uploaders do
   collection { post :upload_file }
end

resources :importers do
   collection { post :import_vendor_ledger, :import_chart_of_accounts }
end
```

index.html.haml

```
#chart_of_accounts
  = form_tag upload_file_uploaders_path, multipart: true do
    = hidden_field_tag :account, "chart_of_accounts"
    = file_field_tag :file
    = submit_tag 'Upload Chart of Accounts'

#vendor_ledger
  = form_tag upload_file_uploaders_path, multipart: true do
    = hidden_field_tag :account, "vendor_ledger"
    = file_field_tag :file
    = submit_tag 'Upload'
```

uploaders_controller.rb

```
class UploadersController < ApplicationController
  include Excel

  def upload_file
    uploaded_io = params[:file]
    if uploaded_io.path.downcase.end_with?(xlsx_extension)
      save_to_storage(uploaded_io)
      flash[:success] = 'File uploaded successfully!'
      redirect_based_on_(params) # this is where it should call the action
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'ERROR: The file you upload MUST be an ".xlsx" excel file!'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  private

  def redirect_based_on_(_params)
    case _params[:account]
    when "vender_ledger"
      redirect_to import_vendor_ledger_importers_path and return
    when "chart_of_accounts"
      redirect_to import_chart_of_accounts_importers_path and return
    end
  end
end
```

importers_controller.rb

```
class ImportersController < ApplicationController
  include Excel

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def import_vendor_ledger  # I can hit this action
    puts "hits vendor ledger import"
  end

  def import_chart_of_accounts  # but I can't hit this action
    puts "hits chart of accounts import"
  end
```

EDIT #1: even if I explicitly call `redirect_to import_chart_of_accounts_importers_path` in `uploaders#upload_file` it still doesn't hit the `importers#import_chart_of_accounts` action

EDIT #2: after inspecting more, it seems that `importers#import_chart_of_accounts` action IS being hit, but none of the functions in the action is being called

Comment: what response you get, when account is `chart_of_accounts` ? any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route to something like this:

```
resources :importers do
  collection do
    get :import_vendor_ledger
    get :import_chart_of_accounts
  end
end
```

EDIT: Since you are redirecting to those two paths, I believe, you need those to be GET routes. Since `redirect_to` issues a `301 request` which will be GET request.